# Electron as a PPA

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, launchpad

I've been doing some research: **You can't build PPA's from a Node.js application**.

Apparently, this is *not a rule*, since there are a few projects that have *successfully* achieve this. **WebUDP8** is an example; they build the PPA's for **Atom IDE** (using Electron) & **Popcorn Time** (using Node-Webkit)

I did what any human being would do: *bother these guys*, since there's no documentation (or at least, none that I found).

Their answer:

> Launchpad PPAs don't support nodejs yet because they don't allow
>   fetching external resources. So the Popcorn TIme PPA used to be a
>   simple installer that automatically downloaded Popcorn Time from its
>   servers. But, as far as I'm aware of, I'm not using external
>   resources. It's not like I am downloading dependences from the
>   package.json. They are all --saved in the folder to build.

How can I make a **PPA of my Electron App**? 
Does the Software Center work with PPA's as well, or only .deb's?

Comment: what if they `npm i --production` then pack all the files including the node_modules into the resulting deb archive ?

Comment: can't make a ppa with the binary :(